# Method that accepts a String and searches for every occurrence and prints how many rimes it occurs

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

Method that accepts a String and searches every occurrence XX and prints how many times XX occurs and prints the letter in between all the occurrences of XX..??

Here's what I have so far and I know it's probably not correct...

```
public void tokens(String s)
{
    String tokenArray[] = s.split("XX");

    for (String s:tokenArray)
        System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Well rather than saying it's "probably" not correct, why don't you find out? Come up with test cases, work out what you expect and what actually happens. You don't really have a question here yet...

Comment: I did, and it's not correct. I just need help with the print statement part...

Comment: "it's not correct" doesn't tell us the input, expected output or actual output. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Wont  `tokenArray.length -1` give you some what the output.. Btw fearful to post in jon skeet presence xD

Comment: PLEASE POST! I want to see what you have!

Comment: You wil have to edit your question first. As Jon Skeet said tell what is happening in that code... Provide some input-output examples then only we could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same variable "s" twice, once as the method parameter and once in the for loop.

Just changing the variable name in the for loop should print the tokens correctly:

```
for (String tokens : tokenArray)
        System.out.println(tokens);
```